# Mathjax formatting buttons for you guys!

Tags: discussion, mathjax

After having to add dollar signs and format SI  units countless times in the review section on Physics, I finally got fed up and wrote a script.{*}

It basically adds buttons/keyboard shortcuts to enclose the selected text in dollar symbols. (it does more, but that functionality is hidden for math.SE)

It's pretty useful in `/review`, and also a good shortcut when writing your own posts.

[Here's the userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons). Installation instructions are there. (also bugs/feature reqs/whatever)

<sup>*With [some urging from chem.SE.people](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/whats-the-policy-on-systems-of-measure#comment28_39), otherwise it was going to be indefinitely in my todo list :P</sup>

Answer (score 2):

### Note to users who installed it before 5/5/12 (3:51 PM UTC):

The script no longer needs to be updated (most updates include the addition of more sites/buttons and tweaks like tooltips). It auto-fetches the updates now.

I suggest you uninstall/reinstall it to run this one-time update

How to uninstall:

- Chrome: Settings>Tools>Extensions. Find the script and delete it
- Firefox: Open the GM settings and remove the script

Then re-install normally ([click here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js))

Comment: Installed. Looks nice. Thank you.

Comment: great! be sure to list it on http://stackapps.com?tab=scripts as well

Comment: @jeff it already is there, see main post http://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons ;-)